# js setTimeout() finishes instantly without any rest

Tags: javascript

when coding, I came upon this very weird problem. My code is below:
js

```js
document.getElementById("id").style.width = "0%"
var a = 0;
setTimeout(function () {
    if (a <= 60) {
        document.getElementById("id").style.width = a + "%";
        a++;
    }
}, 100);
```

I want it to run 60 times, each time changing the div's width by 1%
However, when I run the code, the if block makes it finish instantly as if the timeout didn't work. Can anyone tell me what's wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are aware that `100` is `100ms`, and that it runs only once?

Comment: It looks like you're animating an element's CSS properties. You shouldn't use JS for that (let alone `setTimeout`). Use `@keyframes` in CSS instead. If you _must_ use JS then use `requestAnimationFrame`.

Comment: the time you entered is in milliseconds. so its 100 milliseconds if you set it as 1000 it will 1 second

Comment: @connexo, what do you exactly mean?

Comment: Please describe precisely what you expect your code to do.

Comment: @connexo I want it to run 60 times, each time changing the div's width by 1%

Comment: `setTimeout` runs code only once, after at least the time specified. Use `setInterval` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setTimeout` function executes only once after that specified time in milli seconds.

If you want to keep on executing the block, you have to make use of `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`.

`setInterval` keeps on calling the function since the interval is cleared.

Dont forget to call `clearInterval` once target achieved.

```js
var a = 0;
const interval = setInterval(function () {
    if (a <= 60) {
        console.log("Im being called");
        document.getElementById("id").style.width = a + "%";
        a++;
    } else {
      // Target achieved, clearing interval
      console.log("Im stoping execution");
      clearInterval(interval)
    }
}, 100);
```

```css
#id {
  height: 300px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="id"></div>
```

Comment: does interval have to be defined as a variable?

Comment: @mm4096 Yes, otherwise you cannot clear it, which would mean it runs indefinitely. Still for what you are doing Javascript definitely is the wrong tool. Use CSS and `@keyframes` animation instead.

Comment: @mm4096. Yes. You should clear it once your requirement is achieved. Fo that it should be stored in some memory location.

Comment: ok, thank you. I'll accept it as soon as I can.